# datetime showing different type in the database and other different on the web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, gregorian-calendar, hijri

I have in my database a datetime field the value presented in the database in normal format which is Gregorian. But when I present the datetime in a gridview on an asp.net webforms application it presented in hijri. how can I specify the calendar to be presented as in the database in the Gregorian calendar.

Note, just to be clear Gregorian  the most common one which is

```
26/06/2019
```

and the hijri is the arabic one which presented like below

```
23/10/1440
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the date to be displayed according to the visitor's regional settings? Please show us some code too.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti yes I'm sure

Comment: Is you database and application server are different ?, if yes then check the timezone, is this same on both the machine

Comment: both in the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Change the CultureInfo from en-GB to whatever you need:

```
var myDateTimeFormatInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat;
var formattedDate = myDate.ToString(myDateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern);
```

If you want to do this page-wide, take a read at https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/12062/Localization/How-to-Set-a-Culture-for-an-ASP-NET-Web-Page

Comment: from do I get my region shortcut

Comment: Did this fix your issue @AbdallahRizk?